# Hyperlink in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, hyperlink

I am developing a Mac application in XCode. I need to add a hyperlink which navigates to a particular site. I tried this using a button, but I need to know how to change the cursor to hand cursor when mouse is over that button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can use a non-editable NSTextField to display the URL. If you set the attributes appropriately on the NSAttributedString that you set as the field's value property, it will display as the standard blue-with-underline and handle the cursor tracking for you. [This](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2006/qa1487.html) Apple Q&A tells you how to set the attributes for a URL.

Comment: The only issue with this Apple tech note is that the mouse cursor still changes to the I-beam text entry style cursor on mouse over.

Comment: One more issue is that clicking the link changes the font of the NSTextField to the system default. The following fixes that glitch for me by forcing the text to inherit the text field's font: `[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[label font] range:NSMakeRange(0, [attString length])];`

Answer (score 4):

To set the cursor, you have to use the cursor tracking method `addCursorRect:cursor:`. However, you are really only supposed to call that method from inside the `resetCursorRects` method. If you do it at any other time, it's basically guaranteed to be ignored.

So this means you need to subclass `NSButton` (or whatever `NSView` subclass you want to use) and override `resetCursorRects` to call `addCursorRect:cursor:` for the entire view's `bounds`.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly, thanks. I have subclassed NSTextField.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to throw in an updated answer for whomever stumbles upon this next.

I found that when I tried the solution specified by the Apple Q&A in Barry's answer, that the text of my label link would shrink when it was clicked.  After some debugging, I figured out that the sample code on Apple's article was setting a new attributed string, but wasn't preserving any of the original attributes on the label control to begin with.  The solution is to simply start with a copy of the label's original attributed string, add the new hyperlink properties, and then update the label.

I've made a simple helper function that turns an NSTextField label into a hyperlink. It basically consolidates the solution on Apple's page without the need to add a category extension to NSAttributeString.

```
// Converts an otherwise plain NSTextField label into a hyperlink
-(void)updateControl:(NSTextField*)control withHyperlink:(NSString*)strURL
{
    // both are needed, otherwise hyperlink won't accept mousedown
    [control setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
    [control setSelectable: YES];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];

    NSAttributedString* attrString = [control attributedStringValue];

    NSMutableAttributedString* attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attrString];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attr length]);

    [attr addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:range];
    [attr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor blueColor] range:range ];
    [attr addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:range];

    [control setAttributedStringValue:attr];
}
```

And then to invoke it, pass the NSTextField and url string into it sometime when the window initializes:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [self updateControl:_label withHyperlink:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

}
```